# Scala: from Array[String] to Array[Array[String]]

Tags: arrays, scala, multidimensional-array

I have an `Array[String]` in scala like this

```
my_array: Array[String] = Array(RED;BLUE, RED;PINK, RED;ORANGE, RED;WHITE, RED;YELLOW, 
RED;GREY,GREEN;BLUE, GREEN;PINK, GREEN;BROWN, GREEN;ORANGE, GREEN;WHITE, GREEN;YELLOW, GREEN;GREY)
```

and I need to get this result

```
my_new_array: Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(RED;BLUE, RED;PINK, RED;ORANGE, RED;WHITE,RED;YELLOW, RED;GREY), 
Array(GREEN;BLUE, GREEN;PINK, GREEN;BROWN, GREEN;ORANGE, GREEN;WHITE, GREEN;YELLOW, GREEN;GREY), 
Array(RED;BLUE, GREEN;BLUE), Array(RED;PINK, GREEN;PINK), 
Array(RED;ORANGE, GREEN;ORANGE), Array(RED;WHITE, GREEN;WHITE),    
Array(RED;YELLOW, GREEN;YELLOW), Array(RED;GREY, GREEN;GREY))
```

These should be te steps

- get a list of unique colors. this means I have to split by ";" each string
- once I have this list I have to create a new Array contained the original strings grouped by each single color

Does anyone have an hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provided I've understood your question correctly, this should work (probably not the most efficient solution ever)

```
myArray
.flatMap(_.split(';'))                      // get all the colors
.distinct                                   // get the unique set of colors
.map(color => myArray.filter(_.contains(color)))  // map each color to each group containing it
```

I'm using `contains` assuming that for `"YELLOW"` you want to match both `"YELLOW";"RED"` and `"RED";"YELLOW"`.

In case you want to match only the former, you can use `startsWith` intead.

Comment: x should be myArray in the last map statement. x does not exist.